# Obtaining the actual value from the pulse signal, discrete signal and continuous signal

Tags: c++, algorithm, matlab, signal-processing

I have two questions, the first question is about pulse signal. I have a 0 - 1 pulse signal with a constant pulse length of about 19 ms from special fuel measurement system. The breaks between the pulses are different and depends on the current fuel consumption. One pulse is 0.01 liter. On the basis of the frequency of impulses and breaks between them, he wants to calculate the combustion of fuel for example in window that has 10 second.

I do not know how I can do it. Can someone recommend me some algorithms that I can use.

The second question is how to move from a discrete signal to a continuous signal.I know that there are algorithms like zoh but I do not know how I can implement it. Does anyone have any other ideas ?

I have pulse signal from fuel measurement system and I have discrete signal RPM from OBD, but I need convert this signal to continuous.

Comment: The *signal processing* site seems more adapted to this question

Comment: I think you'll find that both of these questions are related to counting pulses within a time windows, which can be expressed as a percentile. Such a percentile can be used to reproduce a continuous (linear) signal. I hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Just count number of pulses in last 10 seconds.

Using queue data structure, you can add new pulse event to the head and check whether tail item is in time range, removing too old ones. Queue size corresponds to fuel consumption (with `0.01 liter/10 seconds` coefficient).